# Selenium File upload dialog pop-up window not closed

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I am using the below code snippet for file upload using selenium in Java. The path of the file is successfully paste on the dialog pop-up but the dialog window is not closed or you say the 'open' button on dialog window is not pressed. I think the focus on this 'open' button is change somehow. This will cause to unable my file to upload. Please suggest!

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;

public static void setClipboardData(String string) {
  StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
 And that is what i do, just after opening the "open" window:
 setClipboardData("C:\\path to file\\example.jpg");
 //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use that `Robot` class. If you have the file upload button and you have it stored as a `WebElement` you can just do this:

```
//element is a WebElement of the upload button e.g.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("upload_btn"))
element.sendKeys("C:\\pathToFile\\example.jpg");
```